# Does python support string indexed variables and the variables are references?

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following strings: "a", "b" and "c" and I have 3 variables, var_a, var_b and var_c.

I like to put them into some data structure so that the strings serve as indexes to the variables:

```
"a" --> var_a
"b" --> var_b
"c" --> var_c
```

The key is, I need to have those variables references.

The end goal is, I like to retrieve the right variable from a given string and update the variable's value. Here is the pseudo code:

```
update("a", 100) ==> var_a is assigned to 100 now.
update("b", 200) ==> var_b is assigned to 200 now
```

I can use any version of python.

Thanks!

[**UPDATE**]
Let me clarify the use case.

I have the following 2 data files.

```
data_file_1:
I like to give you $var_a donuts for exchange of $var_b muffins.

data_file_2:
var_a = 100
var_b = 200
```

My program parses both files and need to update the string from data_file_1 into:
`I like to give you 100 donuts for exchange of 200 muffins`.

Hopefully you can see why I ask the question. Bottom-line, I do not want to write a lot of repetitive string matching code.

Comment: [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)?

Comment: Could you please show an example of some code where you _need to have the variable references_ and yet you want to update them the way you describe?

Comment: You don't need the variables at all - just use a dict.

Comment: What's the use case for this lookup anyway? You have the variables and know their names, just assign them new values

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like what you want to do can probably be accomplished with [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

*Ideally*, you would change the format of your sentence so that it's stored something like this in the file:

```
I would like to give you {a} donuts in exchange for {b} muffins.
```

But if you're working from a fixed format, you could read it in to a variable, then alter it with a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```py
import re

sentence = "I would like to give you $var_a donuts in exchange for $var_b muffins."
sentence = re.sub(r'\$var_([\w]+)', r'{\1}', sentence)
print(sentence)
# I would like to give you {a} donuts in exchange for {b} muffins.
```

Then, read the file containing the values into a dictionary. If it looks like your example, you could do so like this...

```py
values = {} 

with open('data_file_2') as f:
    for line in f:
        var, value = line.rstrip().split(' = ')
        var_name = var.removeprefix('var_')
        values[var_name] = value
```

Once you have your dictionary, supply it to the format method:

```py
values = {'a': 100, 'b': 200}

print(sentence.format(**values))
# I would like to give you 100 donuts in exchange for 200 muffins.
```

Comment: You could also use [`string.Template`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) for this kind of syntax.

Answer (score -2):

I think that you can use `globals()` and `locals()` dictionary in order to dynamically create and update variables as follows:

```
# you can choose the scope of variables by using either locals() or globals()
def update(k, v):
    globals()[f"var_{k}"] = v
    print(f"var_{k} is assigned to {v} now.")

def update_local(k, v):
    locals()[f"var_{k}"] = v
    print(f"var_local_{k} is assigned to {v} now.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    update("a", 100)
    update("b", 200)
    print(f"[main] var_a: {var_a}, var_b: {var_b}")
    update_local("a", 100)
    update_local("b", 200)
    print(f"[main] var_local_a: {var_local_a}, var_local_b: {var_local_b}")
```

Result:

```
var_a is assigned to 100 now.
var_b is assigned to 200 now.
[main] var_a: 100, var_b: 200
var_local_a is assigned to 100 now.
var_local_b is assigned to 200 now.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xx.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(f"[main] var_local_a: {var_local_a}, var_local_b: {var_local_b}")
NameError: name 'var_local_a' is not defined
```

Comment: Modifying `locals()` is undefined behavior, including through `exec`, and just using an explicit dict handles this use case much better.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica We do not know the use case of the OP in advance, your remark could change OP's intention. I have assumed that OP understands the meaning of variable scope.

Comment: The variable name may come from anywhere, running it through `exec` is potentially dangerous if it is user input. Assigning to the dict returned from globals/locals is still a bit janky but less dangerous: `globals()[f'var_{k}'] = v`

Comment: @lain Shelvington That's a good point. I changed my answer according to your suggestion.